# Smarty no visualiza variable php

Tags: php

Desde un formulario envío user y clave.

```
$usuario = new usuario();
$u = $usuario->login($_POST['user'], $_POST['clave']);
$_SESSION['USUARIO_ACTUAL'] = serialize($u);
$tpl = new Plantilla();
$tpl->assign('VARIABLE', unserialize($_SESSION['USUARIO_ACTUAL']));
$tpl->display("variable.tpl.php");
```

La clase login:

```
function login($user, $pass){

$query = "SELECT usuario, clave, acceso FROM users WHERE usuario = :usuario_in AND clave = :clave_in";

$BD = new ConexionDB();
$recordSet = $BD->prepare($query);
$recordSet->bindParam('usuario_in', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recordSet->bindParam('clave_in', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recordSet->execute();

while ($fila = $recordSet->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$usuario = new UsuarioVO($fila['usuario'], $fila['clave'], $fila['acceso']);
}
return $usuario;
}
```

Y en la vista quiero visualizar al usuario:

```
{$VARIABLE->usuario}
```

Pero me muestra: *Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in compilador smarty*
*Call Stack*

Al hacer *print_r($u)* me muestra:

```
UsuarioVO Object ( [usuario] => ADMINIS [clave] => tecsup [acceso] => 0 )
```

Comment: y que ves si haces un `print_r($usuario)`